# How to properly read all changed entities from external API

Tags: algorithm

I need to properly traverse over all items in some external API. All items have "update_time" property and I can query the items from API in ascending or descending order. Which I should use to properly get all items without missing any of them?

Facts:

- External API has pagination (limit and page parameters are fixed) and I cannot query all items by one query.
- Querying of items takes some time.
- Processing of received items takes some time.
- While a page of items is queried or processed, items in external system can be changed -> this cause updating its 'update_time' property and influence ordering (paginating), so next page API call can cause "gap" in list of received items.

I don't want to process all items every time - only updated ones by the last traverse (this task is scheduled every 1 hour for example) - I store max of "last_update" property of all received items and skip processing of older items next traverse.

Thanks, it's really complicated to imagine for me.

Comment: According to small amount of information, it's to **broad**.

Comment: If your items are changing underneath you while the query is evaluated, there's nothing you can do except query again to get the latest results. You say you can query in descending order, so do that on the update_time.